# Reg Ex trying to find and replace all twitter mentions and hashtags Notepad ++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to find and remove all twitter mentions (starts with @, the followed with twitter username. Alphanumeric characters (upper and lower case letters and numbers) and underscores.

Additionally for my next step I'd like to remove all of the hashtags in the text file. A hashtag start with the # sign and any number of characters not followed with spaces or tabs.

I'll be using notepad ++ to find and remove these instances.

So far this is what I have:

@[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,15} for the first one works, but not if there is the same mentioned username twice. For example:
[image]

## [a-zA-Z0-9] is working but only matches the hashtag and the first character. For example:

[image]

Here's a few lines of the text I'm working with:

```
posted: Sat Feb 03 2018 11:05:14    text: I should be making a killing for mining all this stale DSH coin, minergate. #bitcoin #ripple #altcoin screen_name: carlosrr24 location: Providence, RI    verified: false followers_count: 629    friends_count: 139  lang: en    retweet_count: 0    favorite_count: 0
posted: Sat Feb 03 2018 11:05:14    text: @cryptodailyuk @ADAcoin_ @BittrexExchange @exchange @NEWS @Bitcoin @crypto @_CryptoIQ @CharlieShrem Well done! Shut the fkn tether down!  screen_name: Pascal74672564 location: Zrich, Schweiz    verified: false followers_count: 6  friends_count: 16   lang: de    retweet_count: 0    favorite_count: 0
posted: Sat Feb 03 2018 11:05:27    text: When @Bitcoin becomes number 2 market cap, can I call it an Alt coin?     screen_name: Steven_Budgen84    location: Bahrain   verified: false followers_count: 238    friends_count: 1394 lang: en    retweet_count: 0    favorite_count: 0
posted: Sat Feb 03 2018 11:05:35    text: Current price of Bitcoin is $8844.61 #Bitcoin #Bithound   screen_name: The_BitHound   location: United States verified: false followers_count: 87 friends_count: 237  lang: en    retweet_count: 0    favorite_count: 0
posted: Sat Feb 03 2018 11:05:52    text: THE MOST INNOVATIVE AND LUCRATIVE WAY TO EARN BITCOIN JOIN BITCLUB NETWORK! ! !   screen_name: toshi_mat003   location: null  verified: false followers_count: 37 friends_count: 7    lang: ja    retweet_count: 0    favorite_count: 0
posted: Sat Feb 03 2018 11:05:56    text: THE MOST INNOVATIVE AND LUCRATIVE WAY TO EARN BITCOIN JOIN BITCLUB NETWORK!!! screen_name: Bitclubnetwork3    location: Australia verified: false followers_count: 106    friends_count: 58   lang: ja    retweet_count: 0    favorite_count: 0
```

Comment: Paste a few lines of your test data so people can experiment with it.

Comment: Show your whole pattern. There's no reason `@[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,15}` doesn't work (except that it doesn't match the underscore).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte just added the _ to the expression. But as you can see in the first image above, only some instances are found when there are multiple mentions.

Comment: @Brad: one more time: SHOW THE WHOLE PATTERN.

Comment: Easy now. Just posted the lines of text above.

Comment: @Brad: No, show the whole regex pattern.

Comment: @[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,15} is the whole pattern that I have right now.

Comment: @Brad: are you sure you don't have leading or trailing spaces in it? Or look at the options in the dialog box (sorry I can't test it now since I just reinstall my system).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte 10000000% certain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For usernames**:

Your suggested regex of `@[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,15}` misses those usernames with underscores in them. It doesn't match `@ADAcoin_` and `@_CryptoIQ` in your search text. Use `@\w{1,15}` instead.

Also, when you say that the search fails "if  there is the same mentioned username twice", I think you're being misled by the way the results of the search are presented. If you look to the left, you'll see that each line highlights different matches on the same line. In the image I've attached, the regex finds all nine matches on the same line (Line 3), but it prints each match on a separate line.

[image: All the matches are on line 3]

**For hashtags**:

`(#[^\s]+\s)` Note the trailing whitespace - if I'm not mistaken, multiple hashtags must be separated by spaces.

Comment: You're totally right! I am fairly new with this and totally thought that it was just missing some of the situations. Thank you!